# When Grabbing a File through JFileChooser why does this fail?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, ffmpeg

I'm trying to understand Java Swing GUIs. So I created a simple GUI to select a File.

When I attempt to use the FFMPEG wrapper to get file information I get the following error.

`java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\File.mp4": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application.`

I feel like I'm missing something minor here.
Thanks.

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
int nReturnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(jPanel1);
File fVideo = null;
try {
    if (nReturnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        fVideo = fc.getSelectedFile();
        //Now you have your file to do whatever you want to do
        jPath.setText(fVideo.getAbsolutePath());
        
        FFprobe ffprobe = new FFprobe(fVideo.getAbsoluteFile().toString());
        FFmpegProbeResult probeResult = ffprobe.probe(fVideo.getAbsolutePath());
        FFmpegFormat format = probeResult.getFormat();
        
        System.out.format("%nFile: '%s' ; Format: '%s' ; Duration: %.3fs",
                format.filename,
                format.format_long_name,
                format.duration);
        
        jEndTime.setText("" +  format.duration);
        
    } else {
        //User did not choose a valid file
    }
} 
catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.toString());
}
```

Comment: What library wrapper are you using - it would seem that `FFprobe` is expecting you to pass the executable and not the file you want to parse

Comment: I'm using this wrapper https://github.com/bramp/ffmpeg-cli-wrapper

Comment: Just as the "documentation" states `FFprobe ffprobe = new FFprobe("/path/to/ffprobe");` - you need to pass the path of the executable to the constructor, not the file you want to process, you then use `FFmpegBuilder builder = new FFmpegBuilder().setInput("input.mp4")` to set the input

Comment: I actually see what is going wrong. Thank you. I feel dumb.